# how to sort a 2d array in Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an array like this.
asd = [[a,3],[b,1],[c,5],[d,2]];

I want to sort it from the number resulting like,

asd = [[a,5],[b,3],[c,2],[d,1]];

Any one knows an apps script code?

Comment: This sounds like a JavaScript question. Anyway, a few questions: Will the array always be in the form of [letter, number]? You want to have the letters alphabetically ordered, and the numbers descending, even if this means modifying the array? Are you looking for a solution to work exclusively in google apps script, or one that affects the cells in the spreadsheet? Please consider answering such questions, so we can accurately help you.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2):

How about following sample? a, b, c, and d were used as strings. This can be executed on Google Script Editor.

**Sample script :**

```
var asd = [['a',3],['b',1],['c',5],['d',2]];

var result = [[asd[i][0],[i[1] for each (i in asd)].sort(
  function(a,b){
        if( a > b ) return -1;
        if( a < b ) return 1;
        return 0;
})[i]] for (i in asd)];
```

**Result :**

```
[[a, 5.0], [b, 3.0], [c, 2.0], [d, 1.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you wanted to achieve, this code should work:

```
var arr = [["a",3],["b",1],["c",5],["d",2]];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
 for (var j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
  if (i==arr.length-1) continue;
  var thisItem = arr[i],
      nextItem = arr[j];
  if (thisItem[0] > nextItem[0]) {
    var tempL = nextItem[0];
    nextItem[0] = thisItem[0];
    thisItem[0] = tempL;
  }

  if (thisItem[1] < nextItem[1]) {
    var tempN = nextItem[1];
    nextItem[1] = thisItem[1];
    thisItem[1] = temp;
  }
 }
}
```